# Unable to install bootstrap 12.1.2 on Angular14

Tags: angular

Following Error is being given when installing Bootstrap 12.1.2 on Angular 14 with npm

While resolving: sampleapp@0.0.0
Found: @angular/common@14.0.0
node_modules/@angular/common
@angular/common@"^14.0.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0" from @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2
node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@"*" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

{
"code": "ERESOLVE",
"current": {
"name": "@angular/common",
"version": "14.0.0",
"whileInstalling": {
"name": "sampleapp",
"version": "0.0.0",
"path": "C:\Users\hp\sampleapp"
},
"location": "node_modules/@angular/common",
"isWorkspace": false,
"dependents": [
{
"type": "prod",
"name": "@angular/common",
"spec": "^14.0.0",
"from": {
"location": "C:\Users\hp\sampleapp"
}
}
]
},
"currentEdge": {
"type": "prod",
"name": "@angular/common",
"spec": "^14.0.0",
"from": {
"location": "C:\Users\hp\sampleapp"
}
},
"edge": {
"type": "peer",
"name": "@angular/common",
"spec": "^13.0.0",
"error": "INVALID",
"from": {
"name": "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap",
"version": "12.1.2",
"whileInstalling": {
"name": "sampleapp",
"version": "0.0.0",
"path": "C:\Users\hp\sampleapp"
},
"location": "node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap",
"isWorkspace": false,
"dependents": [
{
"type": "prod",
"name": "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap",
"spec": "*",
"from": {
"location": "C:\Users\hp\sampleapp"
}
}
]
}
},
"strictPeerDeps": false,
"force": false
}

Comment: 14 is not yet supported.. but it’s coming: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/4340

Comment: Have you tried using `ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`?